# Examples of theorems in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, big-list

I'm looking for examples of uses of the incidence matrix in graphs for my class (apart from proving that for a graph $G=(V,E)$ we have $2|E|=\underset{v\in V}{\sum}d(v)$).
Can you think of anything interesting?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe you should mention the background which the students have. Also I have flagged this to make community wiki.

Comment: Is this the incidence matrix or the adjacency matrix you're talking about?

Comment: What Linear Algebra background do they have? (and possibly other topics). Maybe you should mention something like a US undegraduate: sophomore or something like that too...

Comment: It's the incidence matrix. The linear algebra background is from systems of linear equations up to linear operators, diadonalization , PDT and operators in inner-product spaces. They are first-year undergrads.

Comment: @Dennis: the matrix whose powers describe the number of paths of a given length is the adjacency matrix, not the incidence matrix. Which matrix are you talking about?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Oops, I was talking about the incidence matrix, but the answer below by lhf cought me of guard, since we talked about the adjacency matrix as well. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $R(V), R(E)$ the free $R$-modules on the vertices and edges, respectively. Pick an orientation of the graph (an arrow attached to each edge pointing from one vertex to the other). The *oriented* incidence matrix is the matrix of an $R$-module homomorphism

$$\partial : R(E) \to R(V)$$

sending an edge $e$ to $v - w$, where $v, w$ are the vertices in the appropriate orientation. This morphism, and in particular its kernel, is a basic invariant of the graph: when $R = \mathbb{Z}$ or $R = \mathbb{F}_2$ its kernel is the integral (resp. mod $2$) [cycle space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) of the graph, which is a useful tool in answering certain questions in graph theory (the Wikipedia article has references). Abstractly this is a simple example of a [simplicial homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology) group. (Note that you don't have to pick an orientation if $R$ has characteristic $2$. This is familiar behavior from algebraic topology.)

The transpose of the incidence matrix is the matrix of a homomorphism

$$d : R^V \to R^E$$

in the other direction (where $R^S$ is the $R$-module of functions $S \to R$) dual to the above one. It sends a function $f(v)$ on vertices to the function $df(e) = f(v) - f(w)$ on edges and can be thought of as a simple analogue of the derivative. In fact this whole setup is a simple analogue of [de Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology) and [Hodge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory) and one can get the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) naturally this way as well.

The operators above naturally occur if one thinks of graphs as circuits. In fact, [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) can be naturally stated using them when $R = \mathbb{R}$: an element $I \in \mathbb{R}(E)$ can be interpreted as a list of currents if and only if

$$\partial I = 0$$

and an element $e \in R^E$ can be interpreted as a list of potential differences if and only if there exists $\phi \in R^V$ (the potential) such that

$$d \phi = e.$$

The material about circuits should be in Bollobás' [Modern Graph Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=SbZKSZ-1qrwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bollobas+modern+graph+theory), and for more information Doyle and Snell's [Random Walks and Electrical Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001057) is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

A classic example is the [Friendship theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph#Friendship_theorem) of Erdős and Rényi.

Comment: I think this one has proofs using both Incidence and Adjacency matrix but I was thinking of the proof using the adjacency matrix when I posted this!

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix provide bounds on the chromatic number $\chi(G)$.

For a graph $G$, let $\mu_\max(G)$ and $\mu_\min(G)$ be the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix.  Note $\mu_\min(G) < 0 < \mu_\max(G)$ if $G$ is not empty.

All nonempty graphs satisfy
$$1 - \frac{\mu_\max(G)}{\mu_\min(G)} \leq \chi(G) \leq \mu_\max(G) + 1.$$

This is proven in Bollobás' *Modern Graph Theory*.

Comment: Whoops, you were looking for uses of the incidence matrix, and I provided something regarding the adjacency matrix.  I will try to contribute something relevant, too.

Answer (score -1):

There is also the classical result that the powers of the adjacency matrix describe the number of paths of a given length between two vertices.

Comment: Oops, this is about the *adjacency* matrix, not the *incidence* matrix.